# I installed a registry to change my keyboard layout. How do I uninstall

Tags: keyboard, registry, keyboard-layout

I installed A .REG file from minimak.org

I don't know how I can uninstall it. If someone has a .reg that will do the same thing for qwerty, that would be perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A kind lad gave me this answer on reddit
(u/gep1d)

Download the .zip archive from this website: https://colemak.com/Windows and extract it anywhere on your computer. Run Clear remapping.reg from the i386 directory, then reboot your computer (logging out is not enough).